# Dates are not converted in Unix Timestamp from C#

Tags: c#, jquery, datetime

I have a method in which I call a method that performs a query returning an IEnumerable of objects, than I perform a group by Linq on this IEnumerable, and elaborate the result of the grouping to insert it in a JQGrid. The problem I'm having is that when the JQgrid is passed to the js file, the dates are not in the format /Date(milliseconds)/, but are formatted as a string, and I cannot localize them in the grid. 
This is the call to method that performs the query, returning the IEnumerable object:

```
IEnumerable documentList = ObjBase.getAll(string.IsNullOrEmpty(columnList) ? null : columnList.Split(';'), sidx, sord, sqlWhere, out totalRows, userid: userId, siteId: siteId);
```

This is the Group By Linq operation on these IEnumerable:

```
    var documentContact = documentList.GroupBy(c => new
    {
        c.CODE_CUSTOMERID,
        c.DESC_CONTACT_NUMBER,
        c.CODE_CUSTOMERTYPEID,
        c.CODE_CONTRACT_ID, 
        c.DESC_CONTRACT_NUMBER,
        c.DESC_CONTRACT_STATES,
    })
    .Select(gcs => new DocumentContact()
    {
        CODE_CUSTOMER_ID = gcs.Key.CODE_CUSTOMERID,
        DESC_CONTACT_NUMBER = gcs.Key.DESC_CONTACT_NUMBER,
        CODE_CUSTOMERTYPEID = gcs.Key.CODE_CUSTOMERTYPEID,
        CODE_CONTRACT_ID = gcs.Key.CODE_CONTRACT_ID,
        DESC_CONTRACT_NUMBER = gcs.Key.DESC_CONTRACT_NUMBER,
        DESC_CONTRACT_STATES = gcs.Key.DESC_CONTRACT_STATES,
        CODE_SITEID = siteId,
        Documents = gcs.ToList(),
    });
```

This is the class of objects that I have after the group by Linq:

```
public class DocumentContact : ObjBase
{
    public long? CODE_CUSTOMER_ID { get; set; }
    public long? CODE_CUSTOMERTYPEID { get; set; }
    public long? CODE_CONTRACT_ID { get; set; }
    public long CODE_SITEID { get; set; }
    public string DESC_CONTACT_NUMBER { get; set; }
    public string DESC_CONTRACT_NUMBER { get; set; }
    public string DESC_CONTRACT_STATES { get; set; }
    public List<DocumentModel> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

This is the DocumentModel class:

```
public class DocumentModel : ObjBase
{
    private long _id;
    private string _documentModel;
    private long? _documentModelTypeId;
    private long? _documentModelIssuingEntityId;
    private string _documentModelFilename;
    private string _documentModelPath;
    private DateTime? _documentModelStart;
    private DateTime? _documentModelEnd;
    private string _documentModelVersion;
    private long _contractId;
    private string _contractNumber;
    private long _contractTypeId;
    private long _contractStateId;
    private string _contractState;
    private long _documentModelStateId;
    private string _documentModelValoId;
    private DateTime? _documentModelUploadDate;
    private byte[] _documentModelContent;
    private long _documentModelFilter;
    private bool _flagDeleted;
    private long _userId;
    private int _orderDocumentModel = 0;
    private string _placeOfIssue;
    private string _issuingEntity;
    private DateTime? _releaseDate;
    private int? _idOpInsert;
    private int? _idOpId;
    private long? _customerId;
    private long? _customerTypeId;
    private string _customerNumber;
    private DateTime? _documentModelInvalidated;
    private bool _flagValidating;
    private string _fileRemotePath;
    private long? _folderId;
    private string _folderName;
    protected new HELPSI_Database HELPSI_Database = Common.HELPSI_Database.HELPSI_Anag;
}
```

What am I missing, or what can I do to localize correctly the dates, considering te the application is multilingual and the date formats are different for the various languages? Thanks

Comment: How look the response from the server? Can you please post the jqGrid setup?

Answer (score 0):

This is the jqGrid setup:

```
function initializeGridDocument(div_content, gridSelector, div_pager, div_empty) {

var gridId = gridSelector;
var pager_top = gridSelector + '_toppager';
var vl = loadCookieGroup();
jQuery(gridSelector).jqGrid("GridUnload");
jQuery(gridSelector).jqGrid({
    loadui: "block",
    mtype: 'POST',
    ajaxGridOptions: {
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    },
    ajaxEditOptions: {
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        datatype: "json"
    },
    ajaxRowOptions: {
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    },
    datatype: "json",
    serializeGridData: function (postData) {
        if (postData.searchField === undefined) postData.searchField = null;
        if (postData.searchString === undefined) postData.searchString = null;
        if (postData.searchOper === undefined) postData.searchOper = null;
        if (postData.columnList === undefined) {
            postData.columnList = $.map($(gridSelector).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel'), function (value, index) {
                if (value.fetched)
                    return value.index;
            }).join(';');
        }
        if ((postData.searchField != undefined) && (postData.searchField != "")) {
            if (postData.searchField.indexOf('DATE_') > -1) {
                if (postData.searchString.match(/Z$/) == null)
                    postData.searchString = mLoc2UTC(postData.searchString, 'L').toISOString();
            }
        }
        postData = $.extend(postData, {
            _search: true,
            userId: $('#hfCODE_USERID').val(),
            siteId: $('#ddl_site_Options').val(),
            stateId: $('#ddl_documentmodelState').val(),
            folderId: $('#chnfolder').val()
        });

        return JSON.stringify(postData);
    },
    url: 'GestioneDocument.aspx/getDocumentList',
    editurl: '',
    colNames: ['', '', '', '', '', '', t('label.customerprovider.contactnumber'), t('label.contractnumber'), t('label.contractsate'), t('label.actions')],//, t('label.documentid'), t('label.type'), t('label.documentstate'), '', t('label.folder'), t('label.filename'), t('label.uploaddate'), t('label.customerprovider.datedocumentmodelstart'), t('label.customerprovider.datedocumentmodelend'), '', t('label.actions')],
    colModel: [
    {
        name: 'CODE_CUSTOMER_ID',
        index: 'CODE_CUSTOMERID',
        jsonmap: 'OGGETTO.CODE_CUSTOMER_ID',
        sortable: false,
        hidden: true
    },
    {
        name: 'CODE_SITEID',
        index: 'CODE_SITEID',
        jsonmap: 'OGGETTO.CODE_SITEID',
        sortable: false,
        hidden: true
    },
    {
        name: 'CODE_CUSTOMERTYPEID',
        index: 'CODE_CUSTOMERTYPEID',
        jsonmap: 'OGGETTO.CODE_CUSTOMERTYPEID',
        sortable: false,
        hidden: true
        },


    {
        name: 'CODE_CONTRACT_ID',
        index: 'CODE_CONTRACT_ID',
        jsonmap: 'OGGETTO.CODE_CONTRACT_ID',
        sortable: false,
        hidden: true
    },
    {
        name: 'imgInfoRequester', label: '', jsonmap: 'OGGETTO.CODE_CUSTOMER_ID', width: 18, fixed: true, align: 'center', search: false, sortable: false,
        formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
            if (rowObject.OGGETTO.CODE_CUSTOMER_ID) {
                switch (rowObject.OGGETTO.CODE_CUSTOMERTYPEID)
                {
                    case 1:
                        return FormatterAccountGridSales(rowObject.OGGETTO.CODE_CUSTOMER_ID, options, rowObject);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        return FormatterContactGridSales(rowObject.OGGETTO.CODE_CUSTOMER_ID, options, rowObject);
                        break;
                }
            }
        } 
    },

    {
        name: 'imgInfor', label: '', jsonmap: 'OGGETTO.CODE_CONTRACT_ID', width: 18, fixed: true, align: 'center', search: false, sortable: false,
        formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
            if (rowObject.OGGETTO.CODE_CONTRACT_ID)
                return FormatterContractInfos(cellvalue, options, rowObject);
            return "";
        }
    },

    {
        name: 'DESC_CONTACT_NUMBER', label: t('label.customerprovider.contactnumber'), index: 'DESC_CONTACT_NUMBER',
        jsonmap: 'OGGETTO.DESC_CONTACT_NUMBER', sortable: true, width: 125, align: 'left', search: true, group: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'cn'] }
    },
    { name: 'DESC_CONTRACT_NUMBER', label: t('label.contractnumber'), index: 'DESC_CONTRACT_NUMBER',
        jsonmap: 'OGGETTO.DESC_CONTRACT_NUMBER', sortable: true, width: 125, align: 'left', search: true, group: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'cn'] }
    },
    {
        name: 'DESC_CONTRACT_STATES', label: t('label.contractsate'), index: 'DESC_CONTRACT_STATES',
        jsonmap: 'OGGETTO.DESC_CONTRACT_STATES', sortable: true, width: 125, align: 'left', search: false, group: true, formatter: 'formatTranslate'
    },


    {
        name: 'CODE_CUSTOMER_ID',
        jsonmap: 'OGGETTO.CODE_CUSTOMER_ID',
        formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
            $.extend(options, {
                idGridReload: gridSelector,
            });

            $.extend(rowObject.OGGETTO, {
                CODE_SITEID: $('#ddl_site_Options').val(),
            });
            return FormatterVerificationAction(cellvalue, options, rowObject);
        },
        sortable: false, search: false,
        width: 450
    }
    ],
    pager: $(div_pager),
    //sortname: "CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_ID",
    sortname: "DESC_CONTACT_NUMBER",
    sortable: true,
    sortorder: 'desc',
    shrinkToFit: true,
    rowNum: 25,
    rowList: [25, 50, 100, 200, 500],
    height: 500,
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: t('label.documents'),
    imgpath: '../JS/jqGrid/themes/basic/images',
    autowidth: true,
    forceFit: true,
    grouping: false,
    groupingView: false,
    multiselect: false,
    toppager: true,
    grouping: vl != 'clear' && vl != '',
    groupingView:
    {
        groupField: [vl],
        groupText: ['<b>{0}</b>&nbsp;<font color=\'blue\'>({1})</font>'],
        groupCollapse: false,
        groupOrder: ['asc'],
        groupDataSorted: true
    },
    footerrow: false,
    userDataOnFooter: false,
    autoencode: false,
    subGrid: hasPrivilegeWithoutAlerting('showdocumentincontract', $('#hfUSER_PRIVILEGES').val()),
    recreateFilter: true,
    jsonReader: {
        root: function (obj) {

            if (obj.d != undefined) obj = obj.d;
            var d = null;
            if (typeof (obj) == "object")
                d = obj;
            else
                d = eval("(" + obj + ")");

            return d.rows;
        },
        repeatitems: false,
        page: function (obj) {
            if (obj.d != undefined) obj = obj.d;
            var d = null;
            if (typeof (obj) == "object")
                d = obj;
            else
                d = eval("(" + obj + ")");
            return d.page;
        },
        total: function (obj) {
            if (obj.d != undefined) obj = obj.d;
            var d = null;
            if (typeof (obj) == "object")
                d = obj;
            else
                d = eval("(" + obj + ")");
            return d.total;
        },
        records: function (obj) {
            if (obj.d != undefined) obj = obj.d;
            var d = null;
            if (typeof (obj) == "object")
                d = obj;
            else
                d = eval("(" + obj + ")");

            return d.records;
        },
        cell: function (obj) {

            if (obj.d != undefined) obj = obj.d;
            var d = null;
            if (typeof (obj) == "object")
                d = obj;
            else
                d = eval("(" + obj + ")");
            return d.OGGETTO;
        } //'OBJ'
    },
    ondblClickRow: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) { },
    beforeRequest: function () {
        var gridid = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#' + gridid + '_toppager_center').remove();
        $('#' + gridid + '_toppager_right').remove();
        return true;
    },
    gridComplete: function () {
        var grid = $(this), recs = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records');
        if (recs > 0) {
            $('#gbox_' + gridId).show();
            $(div_empty).hide();
        } else {
            $('#gbox_' + gridId).hide();
            $(div_empty).show();
        }

        resizeGrid(gridSelector);

        $(gridSelector + '_toppager_center').remove();
        $(gridSelector + '_toppager_right').remove();

        //NA: Chiudo il pannello della ricerca quando effettuo il Refresh della griglia
        jQuery('.ui-icon-refresh').click(function () {
            var searchIsOpen = $('#fbox_' + gridId).is(':visible');
            if (searchIsOpen) {
                $('#fbox_' + gridId + ' .ui-closer').click();
            }
        });

    },
    afterInsertRow: function (rowid, rowdata, rowelem) {
        var existDocument = rowelem.OGGETTO.Documents && rowelem.OGGETTO.Documents.length > 0 ? true : false;
        var contractUserData = {
            documentModelList: rowelem.OGGETTO.Documents
        };
        var userData = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'userData');
        if (!userData)
            userData = [];
        userData[rowid] = contractUserData;
        $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', 'userData', userData);
        if (!existDocument) {
            $('#' + rowid).children("td.sgcollapsed").unbind().html("").removeClass("ui-sgcollapsed sgcollapsed");
        }
    },
    subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridId, rowid) {
        var dati = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'userData');
        if (dati && dati[rowid]) {
            recursiveDateConvert(dati, { onlyDateSet: ['DATE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_START', 'DATE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_END'] });
            var subgridTableId = subgridId + "_t";
            $("#" + subgridId).html("<table id='" + subgridTableId + "'></table>");
            $("#" + subgridTableId).jqGrid({
                datatype: "local",
                autowidth: true,
                shrinktofit: true,
                data: dati[rowid].documentModelList,
                colNames: ['', '', '', t('label.documentid'), t('label.type'), t('label.contractsate'), '', t('label.folder'), t('label.filename'), t('label.uploaddate'), t('label.customerprovider.datedocumentmodelstart'), t('label.customerprovider.datedocumentmodelend'), t('label.actions'), t('label.validate')],
                colModel: [{
                    name: 'CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_ID',
                    index: 'CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_ID',
                    //jsonmap: 'CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_ID',
                    sortable: false,
                    hidden: true
                },
                {
                    name: 'CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_STATE_ID',
                    index: 'CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_STATE_ID',
                   // jsonmap: 'CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_STATE_ID',
                    sortable: false,
                    hidden: true
                },
                {
                    name: 'CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_ID',
                    index: 'CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_ID',
                    //jsonmap: 'CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_ID',
                    sortable: false,
                    formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                        return FormatterDocumentStateImg(cellvalue, options, rowObject);
                    },
                    width: 15,
                    fixed: true
                },
                {
                    name: 'VALO_DOCUMENT_MODEL_ID',
                    index: 'VALO_DOCUMENT_MODEL_ID',
                    //jsonmap: 'VALO_DOCUMENT_MODEL_ID',
                    sortable: true, group: true, label: t('label.documentid'), search: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'cn'] }
                },
                {
                    name: 'documentModelType.DESC_DOCUMENT_MODEL_TYPE',
                    index: 'DESC_DOCUMENT_MODEL_TYPE',
                    //jsonmap: 'documentModelType.DESC_DOCUMENT_MODEL_TYPE',
                    sortable: true,
                    formatter: 'formatTranslate', search: false, group: true, label: t('label.type')
                },
                {
                    name: 'documentModelState.DESC_DOCUMENT_MODEL_STATE',
                    index: 'DESC_DOCUMENT_MODEL_STATE',
                    //jsonmap: 'documentModelState.DESC_DOCUMENT_MODEL_STATE', label: t('label.documentstate'),
                    formatter: 'formatTranslate', search: false,
                    stype: 'select', searchoptions: {
                        sopt: ['eq'],
                        value: "-1:All;1:Active;0:Inactive",

                    },
                    sortable: true, group: true
                },
                {
                    name: 'CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_FOLDER_ID',
                    index: 'CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_FOLDER_ID',
                    //jsonmap: 'CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_FOLDER_ID',
                    sortable: false,
                    hidden: true
                },
                {
                    name: 'DocumentModelFolderName',
                    index: 'DocumentModelFolderName',
                    //jsonmap: 'DocumentModelFolderName', label: t('label.folder'),
                    formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                        $.extend(options, {
                            idGridReload: gridSelector,
                        });

                        $.extend(rowObject.OGGETTO, {
                            CODE_SITEID: $('#ddl_site_Options').val(),
                        });
                        if (hasPrivilegeWithoutAlerting('updatefolderdocument', $('#hfUSER_PRIVILEGES').val())) {
                            return FormatterDocumentFolder(cellvalue, options, rowObject);
                        }
                        else
                            return (cellvalue !== "") ? cellvalue : t('label.notassignedto');
                    },
                    search: false,
                    stype: 'select', searchoptions: {
                        sopt: ['eq'],
                        value: "-1:All;1:Active;0:Inactive",

                    },
                    sortable: true, group: true
                },

                {
                    name: 'DESC_DOCUMENT_MODEL_FILENAME',
                    index: 'DESC_DOCUMENT_MODEL_FILENAME',
                    //jsonmap: 'DESC_DOCUMENT_MODEL_FILENAME',
                    sortable: true,
                    hidden: true, search: false
                },
                {
                    name: 'DATE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_UPLOAD',
                    index: 'DATE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_UPLOAD',
                    //jsonmap: 'DATE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_UPLOAD',
                    formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) { if (cellvalue != null) return dateUTCToUserTimeZoneLocale(cellvalue); else return ''; },
                    sortable: true, search: false, stype: 'text', searchoptions: {
                        sopt: ['lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge'],
                        dataInit: function (elem) {
                            $(elem).datepicker({
                                duration: '',
                                constrainInput: true,
                                changeYear: true,
                                changeMonth: true
                            });

                        }
                    },
                    width: 200
                },
                {
                    name: 'DATE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_START',
                    index: 'DATE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_START',
                    //jsonmap: 'DATE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_START',
                    formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) { if (cellvalue != null) return moment.utc(dotnetDateToJSDate(cellvalue)).format('L'); else return ''; },
                    sortable: true, search: false,
                    width: 200
                },
                {
                    name: 'DATE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_END',
                    index: 'DATE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_END',
                    //jsonmap: 'DATE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_END',
                    formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) { if (cellvalue != null) return moment.utc(dotnetDateToJSDate(cellvalue)).format('L'); else return ''; },
                    sortable: true, search: false,
                    width: 200
                },                       
                {
                    name: 'CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_ID',
                    //jsonmap: 'CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_ID',
                    formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                        $.extend(options, {
                            idGridReload: gridSelector,
                        });

                        $.extend(rowObject.OGGETTO, {
                            CODE_SITEID: $('#ddl_site_Options').val(),
                        });
                        return FormatterDocumentAction(cellvalue, options, rowObject);
                    },
                    sortable: false, search: false,
                    width: 450
                },
                {
                    name: 'FLAG_VALIDATING',
                    index: 'FLAG_VALIDATING',
                    //jsonmap: 'FLAG_VALIDATING',
                    sortable: true,
                    hidden: true
                }],
                height: "100%",
                rowNum: 11,
                sortname: "name",
                idPrefix: "s_" + rowid + "_",
                beforeSelectRow: function (rowID, e) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});

jQuery(gridSelector).jqGrid('navGrid', div_pager, { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: true, refresh: true }, {}, {}, {}, { recreateFilter: true }, {}, {});
jQuery(gridSelector).jqGrid('navGrid',
    pager_top,
    {
        edit: false,
        add: false,
        del: false,
        search: true
    },
    {//search
        recreateFilter: true,
        beforeShowSearch: function(form) {
            $('.ui-reset', form).click(function() {
                //NA: Effettuo il Reset della ricerca azzerando i campi
                var gridSearchIsOpen = $('#fbox_gridDocument').is(':visible');
                if (gridSearchIsOpen) {
                    $('#fbox_gridCocument .ui-closer').click();
                    $('#search_gridDocument_top').click();
                }
            });
        }

    });

$(gridSelector).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', gridSelector + '_toppager', {
    caption: t('label.documentstate'), buttonicon: "ui-icon-document", title: t('label.documentstate'), cursor: 'pointer',
    onClickButton: function () {

        $('#dialogDocumentModelStates').dialog({
            bgiframe: true,
            autoOpen: true,
            width: 800,
            height: 400,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            position: "top",
            zIndex: 3000,
            open: function () {
                loadGridDMS();
                updateElementI18N('dialogDocumentModelStates');
            },
            close: function () { },
            buttons: {
                'button.close': function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Please use the Answer box for answers to the question only. You can [edit] your question to include more information.